# Dynamic array of a custom class in a copy constructor C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

I'm trying to create a dynamic array of a class that I created by defining a pointer of this class in my other class, then when I create the copy constructor of the second class the IDE tells me that the pointer type is not compatible

```
class myClass2 {
private:
        int *size;
        string name;
        myClass1 *list;
        ...
public:
       myClass2(const char &name,const int size);
       ...
};

myClass2::myClass2(const char &name,const int size){
...
       this->size = new int(size);
       myClass1 * pArray[size]; 
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
           pArray[i] = new myClass1();
       }
       list = pArray; //FIXME:incompatible pointer type
};
```

Comment: list is of type myClass1* and pArray is of type myClass2**. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: along with above comment, why are you treating *size* as dynamic member here? *this->size = new int(size);*  Hope this *myClass2 * pArray[size];*  was a typo.

Comment: This `for(int i = 0; i> size; i++)` doesn’t make sense, perhaps you should start with a good C++ book first.

Comment: @JeJo true, I fixed it

Comment: Why? @KillzoneKid

Comment: @DiegoSimonelli Well, I can give you at least one reason why. Learning from a good book will increase your knowledge and understanding and will prevent you from making silly mistakes in the future ;)

Comment: @DiegoSimonelli If `size` is greater or equal to 0 at the beginning, your loop will never run. If `size` is lesser than 0 your loop will run until `i` overflows and becomes negative. I doubt this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have written:

`myClass1 *list;`

It means that `list`'s value will be address of a myClass1 object.
In contructor of `myClass2`, you wrote:

`list = pArray;`

But `pArray` is not an address of a `myClass1` object. your `pArray` is an array used to contains `myClass2*`. So you got error `incompatible pointer type`.

Comment: @Diego Simonelli. Do you understand my idea!

Comment: So what should I do to fix it?

Comment: @DiegoSimonelli please, wait for me a few minutes.

Comment: I just fixed a few typos. I meant to make an array of class1 and then point it to the list. Sorry about that

Comment: you can assign `list = pArray[0]` or `list = pArray[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to point to MyClass2 type from MyClass1 type. That's why there's an incompatible type error. Either extend MyClass1 for MyClass2 and use polymorphism. 
`Myclass1 * pArray[size];`

PS : It is recommended to use the stack for storing variables unless it is not local. You could do, 
`int size;
this->size = size;`